# Android emulator hates me

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, xamarin.android

Sorry for this title but I'm just so mad because not any of the emulators seem to be working for me. Here are the reasons:

1. Built-in Android Emulator - too slow, it won't even deploy the application, stuck at `Starting emulator ...`, mostly gets the error `Emulator cannot be started with VS (unknown provider)`
2. Genymotion - i thought this is my hope but the virtualbox for some reason gives me Blue Screen of Death hence not being able to use this really good, best recommended emulator

   BSOD Technical Information: STOP: 0x0000003B (0x00000000c0000005, 0xFFFFF880010C9710, 0xFFFFF8800DFB8690, 0000000000000000)
3. XAP or Xamarin Android Player - uses VirtualBox as well, won't let me run the emulator, a dialog box appears saying `Failed to start the virtual machine. This indicates you have just installed virtualbox and need to reboot your computer.` Rebooted/restarted the computer a thousand times, same error.

This is too much pain for me as I'm still a beginner in Android Development but seems like it hates me so much.

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz 2.30 GHz
RAM: 8.00 GB
System: Windows 7 64 bit

Btw, I'm working my Android app in Xamarin Visual Studio 2015.

Let me know if I missed any specific details.

Comment: Please have a ready here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2869/android-emulators-not-starting Several suggestions are there, the one which worked was to copy files to %USERPROFILE%\.android\avd. Hope it helps. Another solution is to update Virtual Box (latest stable version) and give it a try.

Comment: At first, that was my problem, but I can now run the emulator. The emulator does appear but gets either, the app not deploying or taking forever and this `Emulator cannot be started with VS (unknown provider)`. Yes, that is the very first thing I did, update the VirtualBox. But still, BSOD. It's just so infuriating. @LuisBeltran

Comment: Have you tried running an emulator directly (not launching it from VS)? Once loaded, then deploy the app via VS

Comment: Android SDK Manager --> Intel HAXM
Although, download prebuilt intel atom x86 images.

Comment: just use xamrin android player

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Intel hardware accelerator manager (HAXM).

It can be downloaded using the android sdk manager. Once downloaded you have to run the installer manually. The installer is located in you android sdk folder, in /extra/Intel subfolder.

After it is installed, any android simulator using an x86 image will run full speed.

Also make sure HyperV is deactivated, and that virtualization is enable in the machine's bios.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I actually already installed this but instead of x86 image, I used the x86_64 one. Now it's running so fast!

Comment: This is a pretty late comment but I'd like to add that PLEASE DO CHECK the Use Host GPU. It works wonders!

Answer (score 0):

Well, first it will be better to check out if all Android SDK packages were properly installed. To do that locate on your computer a software called "Android SDK Manager" and run it. It will shows the status of several different packages.
Check if you already have installed:
1) Android SDK Tools 24.4.1 and 24
2) Android N (API 21)
3) Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)
If you don't have installed, then do it selecting them and clicking on "install packages" button. 
Restart Visual Studio and try to run a simple/demo app.